# Что такое конструктор и зачем он нужен?

Tags: java, ооп

При изучении джавы столкнулся с конструкторами, пересмотрел все видео и статьи но вообще ничего не понял!
пожалуйста объясните мне что такое конструкторы простым языком будто мне 5 лет
(буду благодарен если еще скинете наглядный пример)

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/constructor.php

Comment: https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/konstruktory-slovo-v-java/

Comment: Смотрите на конструктор как на особый вид метода, который вызывается лишь один раз при создании экземпляра объекта в целях его корректной инициализации на основании логики, которую вы закладываете в объект.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> пожалуйста объясните мне что такое конструкторы простым языком будто мне 5 лет

1) В перерыве мультика ты видишь рекламу стола в IKEA - видишь его фото со всех сторон, видишь рекламный ролик, где папа, мама и ты сидите за столом и завтракаете. В голове у тебя возникает образ этого стола (самого стола у вас еще нет) - это в терминах Java класс `Стол`, то есть некая абстракция того чего нет.

2) В субботу папа садится в машинку едет в IKEA и покупает стол и привозит его домой. Вместо стола вы видите кучу разобранных деревяшек, фурнитуру и проч. - он совсем не похож на тот *стол* из рекламы, но не спеши плакать :)

3) Папа достает отвертку, молоток, берет в руки инструкцию по сборке стола и с твоей помощью собирает стол и о чудо - у вас есть *ваш стол*, который точь в точь такой же как и в рекламе!

Теперь, конструктор в терминах Java это инструкция по сборке стола, с помощью которого вы получаете новый объект класса `Стол` - *ваш стол*

```
public class Стол { // реклама в IKEA
   public Стол() {} //инструкция по сборке стола - он же конструктор
} 

Стол вашСтол=new Стол(); // это как раз место где папа взял отвертку и молоток и соорудил `вашСтол`
```

Comment: чудо а не описание

Comment: Пойду кплю стол в Икеа...